# Azure environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Does Azure API has access to environment variables like: AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, AZURE_STORAGE_KEY, ... ?

In the case of AWS, if you export some of those environment variables, the API can access to them. Does the same happen for Azure APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access **AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT** and **AZURE_STORAGE_KEY** with REST API you could refer to :

- AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT

  [List by subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/list) & [List By Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listbyresourcegroup)
- AZURE_STORAGE_KEY

  [List Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listkeys)

As far as I know, it is not supported to access **AZURE_CLIENT_ID** and **AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET** via REST API.

If you want to get them, I think you could use [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) to do it. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key). The **application ID** and **authentication key** are what you are looking for, they are also called  **AZURE_CLIENT_ID** and **AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET** .

For more details about **Azure REST API**,  refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).